# How to assign bootstrap span6 ONCE for ALL simple_form in rails 3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

We would like to use bootstrap span6 in our simple_form. Here is what we are doing now:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@customer, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>    

  <%= f.input :name, :label => t('CompanyName:'), :input_html => { :class => "span6" } %>  
  <%= f.button :submit, t('Save') , :class => BUTTONS_CLS['action'] %>  
<% end %>
```

The problem is that we need add :input_html => {:class => 'span6'} to each and every f.input and there are quite a lot of simple_forms in our rails app. Is there a way we can assign once span6 and apply it to all simple form in the app? Or we have to go one by one to add the input_html => {} to each f.input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `config.input_class` option mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18525036/1729581) was introduces after the release of 2.1.0. That's why you get an error. Using the latest gem version from Github would solve the problem but this version requires Rails 4.

You can override the default behaviour by appending something like this to `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`:

```
%w(StringInput RangeInput CollectionSelectInput GroupedCollectionSelectInput PasswordInput TextInput NumericInput).each do |class_name|
  old_class = "SimpleForm::Inputs::#{class_name}".constantize
  new_class = Class.new(old_class) do
    def input_html_classes
      super.push('span6')
    end
  end
  Object.const_set(class_name, new_class)
end
```

Explanation for the code: I used a bit of metaprogramming in order to avoid writing almost the same code seven times. So this code does the following:

1. It iterates through the array of names of classes that represent various types of fields.
2. Next, it uses `String#constantize` method provided by ActiveSupport to get a class by its name.
3. Next, it dynamically creates a class using `Class#new` (a param passed to `Class#new` is an ancestor class) and defines `input_html_classes` method inside it.
4. Next, it assigns a name to a newly created class.

Finally we have seven classes `StringInput`, `RangeInput` etc with overriden `input_html_classes` method.

Comment: after appending the class after simple_form.rb in rails app and engines, about half of the text input fields get span6. However none of the text box/drop down menus and some of the text input are not changed. Usually the text input fields on top of the form get span6 and bottom ones are not.

Comment: @user938363 my old solution adds `class='span6'` only to those inputs that have `type='text'`. Please try the updated version and let me know if any inputs remain unstyled.

Comment: Almost there. All input field except dropdown not working. It is the <select><option value = xx>..</option></select> which is still unchanged. Tried SelectInput/OptionInput/ListInput and those cause error.

Comment: CollectionSelectInput works for dropdown list. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you put a few words about what the code does? It would be help to learn. thanks.

Comment: @user938363 I added some explanations, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the default class for different elements like button, label, input etc in the simple form configuration file -> config/initializers/simple_form.rb

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.form_class = :simple_form
  config.input_class = :input_class
end
```

Please refer to [this sample file](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form.rb) for more configuration options

Comment: This applies `"simple_form"` as a class on the **form**; it seems OP wants the class applied to each **input** within the form.

Comment: after putting the 2 line config above in /initializers/simple_form.rb, there is NoMethodError: /engines/customerx/config/initializers/simple_form.rb:102:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `input_class=' for Simp
leForm:Module (NoMethodError).

Comment: what is the simple_form version you are using?

Comment: simple_form version 2.1.0

Comment: @user938363 Wouldn't it be cleaner to use only the `config.form_class` line and then in your CSS apply a style to `.simple_form input[type=text], .simple_form textarea`?

Comment: @depa In an ideal world, yes. But the OP says they're using bootstrap which requires a certain class added to each input.

Comment: @DavidBall I don't know about ideal worlds, but OP could use simply `@extend .span6` to apply the styles from `span6` to all form inputs.